# Is it possible to create an app which can run between an ios mobile platform, and a windows desktop platform, without using a web interface?

Tags: java, c++, ios, sockets

Hi i am learning java at the moment, specifically threading and networking which i have found to be very useful in improving my programming skills. i have a java program which consists of a server and a client using sockets. the server attaches a socket to each thread using start() method, and clients can write text which is echoed back by the server. I was wondering, and this seems feasible, if i could write another client in another language such as c++ and have both a c++ client and a java client connected to the echoServer? i am hoping to eventually have a very very simple application for windows written in java, and a very simple application for IOS, both connecting to the same server which is written in java

Comment: You just need to make a good protocol for passing the information back and forward.

Comment: If your iOS app is communicating with your Java server, via a Sockets. Then I'd say more then half your battle is done..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TCP/IP is a standardized protocol, just about every platform has an implementation of it.  So yes, you can have a Java client and a C++ client and a C# client and a Pyphon client and any other client written in any other TCP-enabled language all connected to the same server at the same time.